# How to use generate on a block with SV interfaces

Tags: interface, verilog, system-verilog, generate

I have a need to use a generate for loop to replicate a few module instances that have interfaces in them and I am running into an elaboration issue. I will attempt to show the problem with this example. I have declared a simple interface and then I have created a hierarchical design below with the top module following the interface and then going down. When I run this design using ncverilog I get the following error:

> .write (test_intf.w),
>                        | ncelab: *E,CUIOAI (./test_generate_interface.sv,105|21): Illegal interface port
>   connection through a generate or array instance
>   (test_wrap.genblk1[0].test.test_intf.w) .   test_intf.w write,
>                     | ncelab: *E,CUIMBC (./test_generate_interface.sv,116|18): An interface port declaration
>   must be connected
>   (test_wrap.genblk1[0].test.test_intf_top.write_read).    .read
>   (test_intf.r)

Begin Code----------------

```
interface test_intf
    #(parameter W = 32)
();

logic [(W-1):0] wdata;
logic [(W-1):0] rdata;
logic read;
logic write;

modport w
(
  input write,
  input wdata
);


modport r
(
  input read,
  output rdata
);

endinterface

module test_wrap
#(
  parameter NUM = 5,
  parameter W   = 32
  )
(
 input clk,
 input rst,
 input [(NUM-1):0] [(W-1):0]  wdata,
 input [(NUM-1):0]            write,
 input [(NUM-1):0]            read,
 output [(NUM-1):0] [(W-1):0] rdata
 );

 genvar v;

  generate
   for (v = 0; v < NUM; v++)
     test
     #(.W(W))
     test
     (
      .clk(clk),
      .rst(rst),
      .read(read [v]),
      .write(write [v]),
      .wdata(wdata [v]),
      .rdata(rdata [v])
     );

  endgenerate
 endmodule

module test
#(parameter W = 32)
(
 input            clk,
 input            rst,
 input            read,
 input            write,
 input  [(W-1):0] wdata,
 output [(W-1):0] rdata
 );

test_intf 
#(.W(W))
test_intf
();

assign test_intf.write  = write;
assign test_intf.wdata  = wdata;
assign test_intf.read   = read;
assign rdata  = test_intf.rdata;

test_intf_top
#(.W (W)) 
test_intf_top
(
 .clk  (clk),
 .rst  (rst),
 .test_intf(test_intf)
 );

endmodule

module test_intf_top
#(parameter W = 32)
(
 input clk,
 input rst,
 test_intf test_intf
 );


 write_read
  #(.W(W))
  write_read
  (
   .clk (clk),
   .rst(rst),
   .write (test_intf.w),
   .read (test_intf.r)
  );

 endmodule

 module write_read
 #(parameter W = 32)
 (
  input clk, 
  input rst,
  test_intf.w write,
  test_intf.r read
  );

reg [(W-1):0] counter;

always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
  if (~rst)
    begin
      counter <= '0;
    end
  else
    begin
      if (write.write)
        counter <= write.wdata;
      else if (read.read)
        read.rdata <= counter;
      else
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate your issue on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/) with different simulators. You named your interface instance the same as its declaration name and this is confusing the simulator. Specifically the simulator sees any usage of `test_intf.w` and `test_intf.r` is referring to modeport int the definition definition of `test_intf`; not instantiation with the same name which you intended.

It is recommended you keep the names unique. By changing the instance names I was able to get it to compile and run without errors.

```
//...

module test_wrap
#(
  parameter NUM = 5,
  parameter W   = 32
  )
(
 input clk,
 input rst,
 input [(NUM-1):0] [(W-1):0]  wdata,
 input [(NUM-1):0]            write,
 input [(NUM-1):0]            read,
 output [(NUM-1):0] [(W-1):0] rdata
 );

 genvar v;

  generate
   for (v = 0; v < NUM; v++)
     test
     #(.W(W))
     test_inst // rename instname test to test_inst
     (
      .clk(clk),
      .rst(rst),
      .read(read [v]),
      .write(write [v]),
      .wdata(wdata [v]),
      .rdata(rdata [v])
     );

  endgenerate
endmodule

module test
#(parameter W = 32)
(
 input            clk,
 input            rst,
 input            read,
 input            write,
 input  [(W-1):0] wdata,
 output [(W-1):0] rdata
 );

test_intf 
#(.W(W))
test_if // rename instname test_intf to test_if
();

assign test_if.write  = write; // rename instname test_intf to test_if
assign test_if.wdata  = wdata; // rename instname test_intf to test_if
assign test_if.read   = read; // rename instname test_intf to test_if
assign rdata  = test_if.rdata; // rename instname test_intf to test_if

test_intf_top
#(.W (W)) 
test_if_top // rename instname test_intf_top to test_if_top
(
 .clk  (clk),
 .rst  (rst),
 .test_if(test_if) // rename portname/instname test_intf to test_if
 );

endmodule

module test_intf_top
#(parameter W = 32)
(
 input clk,
 input rst,
 test_intf test_if // rename portname/instname test_intf to test_if
 );


 write_read
  #(.W(W))
  write_read
  (
   .clk (clk),
   .rst(rst),
   .write (test_if.w), // rename instname test_intf to test_if
   .read (test_if.r) // rename instname test_intf to test_if
  );

 endmodule

 // ...
```